# Unified Process Analysis and Software Percentage Confusion

Tags: agile, requirements, rational-unified-process

I want to ask something about Unified Process. In UP, every iteration has its own analysis and implementation steps.

> [image]

But the above image shows something different. After iteration 5, 90% of analysis completed but just 10% of software completed. I can't understand that. In an iteration, codes are about iteration's requirements. So how could be software's completion ratio 10% and requirements' ratio 90%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a good question.

I would try to provide a neutral view based on the analysis & implementation diagram that you have mentioned. Let me try to explain this with an example so that we can have a contextual discussion.

Assume that your organization has come up with the need to build a Human Resources Management System and for some reason or the other it is decided the product will be implemented internally. So, Engineering and HR teams start together on this and first draw up the *high-level requirements*, may be in a quick half-a-day workshop. The teams move forward by doing the detailed analysis followed by the implementations during the iterations. For example, "The System needs to have provision for handling Employee Resignation" could be part of your high-level requirements whereas "The provision for Manager Approval, HR Processing, Due Settlements etc" could be your Analysis. In this case your Analysis & Implementation could look something like:

Iteration#1: 10% Analysis, 0% Implementation

Iteration#2: 20% Analysis, 0% Implementation

Iteration#3: 40% Analysis, 10% Implementation

.

.

.

Again, this could be different if the Senior Management had asked you to provide an *'approximate'* resourcing and cost estimations (just like a formal project). Then you need to perform *a little more detailed analysis* during the first iterations.

Now, let us suppose the same HR System project has come to you from some other organization and you are providing IT services to them. Now, are you starting from ground-zero this time? No. Your customer would come to you with proper requirements document. You need to do sufficient analysis for the estimation and planning. You would have analyzed the system to a decent level before even you start with your high-level design. This itself would be, say, 60% your analysis. The remaining % is what the would be analyzed at micro levels in lateral cycles. [*Under the cover of "iterative model", can you go and tell your customer that you would estimate (and charge him accordingly) on a piece by piece basis? No.*] Because Cost is the major factor here. (Cost to you and Cost to the Customer)

*So, practically speaking the % of analysis done depends on the stage you have entered into the project cycle and the work that was already done before it came to you.* Also, the bandwidth that you have on resourcing/costing factors will play their role too. In the end, there is no *f(x)* formula and it is fact-driven.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

faiz

http://beyondyourcode.com/

Comment: If i don't misunderstand, you mean that in earlier iterations, results may be just analysis, and there may be no software and implementation.  Am i right?

Comment: Yes, if the project is starting from ground-zero where the earlier iterations form high-level requirements gathering and analysis.

Comment: Thought, this discussion would be contextual here - http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Strategic-Vision-Scrum-Looking-Beyond-37631.S.136242307?qid=1e7bbe3b-2af1-4e07-b222-0ee485f57825&trk=group_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=%2Egmp_37631